# Use of Different Languages in Latex and How it Changes the Figure Labelling/Captioning Language

Tags: captions, babel, languages

```
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{5.1}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{Fig 8.5.1}
\caption{}
\label{Fig 8.5.1}
\end{figure}
```

[image: The label should be Fig: 5.1]

This is the image output. The figure caption should be in English but all my images are now captioned/labelled in Russian. The format for my image is "Fig: 5.1" but the language has somehow changed for the image numbering too. How do I fix this? I have tried searching online but have been unable to find a way out.

Comment: You have set Russian as the main language. Is that what you want?

Comment: Nope. My main language is English but I had a few lines of Russian that I needed to write so I used "\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}" I thought this would allow me to write in English and Russian. Everything else seems right but the figures are not being labeled properly.

Comment: As explained in the manual, the main language is the last one. Just reverse them.

Comment: Oh, no wonder I could not find a way out to something that simple. I reversed them but I couldn't write in Russian so I added "\selectlanguage{russian}" before each russian sentence to make it work. And it did! Thank you for your help. I am fairly new to this so I needed help with such a simple task.

Comment: do you _really_ want `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{5.1}` ? that disables all latex numbering???

Comment: Yeah, I need to because the image numberings are not in a sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your main language is English, you should call `babel` as

```
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
```

because the *last* named language will be the main one. Or you can specify `main=`

```
\usepackage[main=english,russian]{babel}
```

and in this case the order is irrelevant.

If you want to insert some phrases in Russian, you shouldn't go the `\selectlanguage{russian}` way. There are `\foreignlanguage` and `otherlanguage*` for this. In the example below, `quote` is just by way of example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[main=english,russian]{babel}

\begin{document}

The Russian phrase \foreignlanguage{russian}{Привет, мир} means
`Hello, world' in English.

If you have longer passages in Russian, such as a quotation,
you can do as follows
\begin{otherlanguage*}{russian}
\begin{quote}
Все счастливые семьи похожи друг на друга, каждая 
несчастливая семья несчастлива по-своему.
\end{quote}
\end{otherlanguage*}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\fbox{\rule{0pt}{30pt}\rule{30pt}{0pt}}

\caption{A figure}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This was very detailed. I did the exact thing and it worked. It was the first time that I wrote LaTeX in two languages. I am really grateful for your time and help. Problem fixed!